# Why VS Code dont suggest subfollders based on package exports field when TS language features loaded?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, package.json

i create NPM package with exports field in package.json

exports have paths with subfolders and without, for example

```json
{
  "exports" {
    "./foo": {/* ... */},
    "./foo/bar": {/* ... */},
  }
}
```

and VS Code suggest both paths but only until JS/TS language features is loaded (status in bottom of window)

Before it lloks like this:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

How can i fix this? maybe change package.json or settings of vscode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make IntelliSense aware of exports in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73335646/how-to-make-intellisense-aware-of-exports-in-package-json) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/58990498/11107541 ?

Comment: @starball looks like its not working, in my case only autocomplete not working, typescript sees type definitions