# Why TypeScript dont see exports of package? (with module: CommonJS and moduleResolution: Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, package.json

i have NPM package that build for ESM and CJS formats in dist folder of package root

- dist/esm - modules with ESM
- dist/cjs - modules with CJS
- dist/types - typings for all of modules

also in package.json there is export field like:

```json
{
  "exports": {
    "./foo": {
      "types": "./dist/types/foo.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/foo.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/foo.js",
      "default": "./dist/esm/foo.js"
    },
    "./bar": {
      "types": "./dist/types/bar/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/bar/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/bar/index.js",
      "default": "./dist/esm/bar/index.js"
    },
    "./hello/world": {
      "types": "./dist/types/hello/world/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/cjs/hello/world/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/hello/world/index.js",
      "default": "./dist/esm/hello/world/index.js"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see foo is a alias for foo.js BUT bar is alias for bar/index.js

and wneh i use this package in other project with TypeScript, tsc dont see bar and hello/world

it see only foo

```
import foo from 'my-pkg/foo' // WORKS FINE 
import bar from 'my-pkg/bar'; // NOT WORKING (cannot find declarations for...)
import helloWorld from 'my-pkg/hello/world'; // NOT WORKING (cannot find declarations for...)
```

Why does it work like that?

In Node.js without TypeScript it works in ESM and CJS fine without errors.

Only TypeScript can not find type definitions

Comment: In addition to what Jared wrote, see https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#dual-commonjses-module-packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not answer your question but is important for what you're trying to accomplish and is too long for a comment.

This isn't going to work the way you've implemented it, at least not at the time I'm writing this. This is unreasonably hard to do, so don't feel bad. And now I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes...

When you *don't* have an `exports` map node will respect your `main` and `module` entries in your package.json and will treat `.js` files the correct way even based on whether they were `import`ed or `require`d as long as you *don't* set the `type` to "module".

But once you add an `exports` map it takes precedence, and **all** .js files will be treated as either CJS or ESM depending on what you set `type` to in package.json, *regardless of whether it's the `import` or `require` path in the `exports` map*. So that gives you three options:

1. Don't use an `exports` map, set `type` to "commonjs" (or omit it) and use the `module` property to point to your ESM entry point.
2. Change all your esm files to .mjs (and add .mjs to all your imports)
3. Change all your cjs files to .cjs (and add .cjs to all your requires)

The problem with options #2 and #3 is that [the Typescript compiler **will not** add it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619058/appending-js-extension-on-relative-import-statements-during-typescript-compilat), and they have [repeatedly refused to implement this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35148).

Worth noting that even though the spec says that the extension for ESM imports should be '.js' in practice pretty much every up-to-date tool (e.g. Typescript, Rollup, Webpack, Vite) and up-to-date engine (e.g. V8, Webkit) will accept '.mjs'.

You can hack your way through it with shell scripts to replace the file extension with `find`/`mv` and `sed` to append the file extension on your import statements, you can do it less hackily by using a real parser to achieve the same outcome, or you can use something like [this package](https://github.com/knightedcodemonkey/duel) that does it for you.

If you want to see all this in action here's an [example I wrote on GitHub](https://github.com/jasmith79/sequable).

And here are some more resources, shout out to Bergi in the comments on the question:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules

https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#dual-commonjses-module-packages

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for you answer, i dont want to change file extensions because there is source map that refers to files and it need to also be changed

im trying to use rxjs solution (this package has inner package.json files for each pathname)

Comment: "i dont want to change file extensions" then you either can't use an exports map in your root package.json, or you can't support both module formats in the same package. There is (at least not as I write this) any way to use the .js file extension for both ESM and CJS in the same package when you have an exports map. You will have to change one or both file extensions or not use the exports map. I think it's dumb too, but I didn't make the rules.

Comment: I already use exports map and typescript works fine, but exports map is the reason of broken autocomplete in vs code - before i used exports it worked fine.

I want to figure out what's wrong with vscode, because it ignores only subfolders in exports but perfectly suggests simple paths

Comment: @krutoo I can only provide limited help with vscode because I don't use it and my autocomplete works fine... **but** the reason I posted this is because vscode is certainly using node under the hood to resolve those imports for intellisense and node is going to error trying to resolve those imports the way you've structured your project, which is quite possibly why your autocomplete is broken. You **must** change the file extension on either your CJS files or your ESM files or both or your project will be unusable for at least one of those, and it will probably fix your autocomplete too.

Comment: Also you say Typescript works fine, but I question whether you've really tried it with both a CJS consumer and a "type": "module" ESM consumer? Because if you try to use your library from vanilla node.js projects of each variety, you'll see the problem I'm talking about.

Comment: as i say early i fix package by rxjs solution and now its works fine, but now vs code correctly sugests import paths ONLY before TS/JS features is loaded, more details here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77278269/13166471. I mark you answer in this queston as done

Comment: yes, i have tests for my package: esm tests and cjs tests, it checks every export by impirt/require. I also check my package in other projects before publish and TypeScript works with different "module" values in config

Answer (score 0):

In the importing workspace tsconfig.json file, set moduleResolution to "Bundler".

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  }
}
```